# Return element at position index. (No ArrayList)

Tags: java

format: get(index):Object.

```
public class MyArrayList {
    public String[] arrays = {};


    public MyArrayList() {
        arrays = new String[10];
    }

    public int get(int i){
        for(int index = 0; index< arrays.length; index++) {

        }
        return i;
    }
}

public class MyArrayListTest {

    static MyArrayList zoo = new MyArrayList();


    public static void printZoo() {
        System.out.print("The zoo now holds " + zoo.size() + " animals: ");
        for (int j = 0; j < zoo.size(); j++) System.out.print(zoo.get(j) + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Testing constructor, add(object) and size() ");
        zoo.add("Ant");
        zoo.add("Bison");
        zoo.add("Camel");
        zoo.add("Dog");
        zoo.add("Elephant");
        zoo.add("Frog");
        zoo.add("Giraffe");
        zoo.add("Horse");
        printZoo();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

With this code it prints out:

Testing constructor, add(object) and size() 
The zoo now holds 10 animals: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Obviously my code for get method is very wrong but instead of printing out the numbers it should print out "Ant","Bison,"Camel" etc.

All help appreciated for code as I'm a very new programmer. Thanks.

Comment: you can use `HashMap` instead by creating `HashMap<Key as Integer, String as Animal Name>` i.e. `HashMap<Integer,String>`

Comment: @VighaneshGursale Is there another way? Want to try not to import any classes

Comment: Yes by creating an Array of Object but it is very seldom to use. Store each object into array and print its value by `toString()` or by `unboxing` it.

Comment: yes, but the method toString() is more commonly used. I am currently looking into this as well

Comment: Um... are you missing code?  There is no extends, add(Object), or size() methods in your MyArrayList class as written.

Comment: @VighaneshGursale Okay, looking at examples online I'm not sure how I can use this for my code? Can you please help?

Comment: @Choirbean Yeah I skipped out a load of code so it's easier to see for you  guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code is technically correct, but if you want to return string values in run time, you must change the value returned in method get to String as in

```
public int get(int i){
for(int index = 0; index< arrays.length; index++) {

}
return i;
```

to

```
public String get(int i){
   return arrays[i];
}
```

Also in your method printZoo(), you have another loop, so i'd imagine your code printing out duplicate values. so why don't you have the printZoo Method dealing with the for loop and the get() method above displaying the values

So Change your get method to the one i have here, and everything should work for you

If it doesn't Work, then try these pieces of Code

**MyArrayList.java**

```
public class MyArrayList{
public String[] arrays = {};
public int i = 0;

public MyArrayList() {
    arrays = new String[10];
}

public void add(String a)throws ListFullException{ //Add to List if Arraylist is not full
    if(i != arrays.length-1){
    arrays[i] = a;
    i++;
    }
    else{ 
        throw new ListFullException("List Full");
    }
}

public String get(int i){

    return arrays[i];
}

public int getArraySize(){
    return arrays.length;
}
}
```

**MyArrayListTest.java**

```
public class MyArrayListTest {

static MyArrayList zoo = new MyArrayList();


public static void printZoo() {
    System.out.print("The zoo now holds " + zoo.getArraySize() + " animals: ");
    for (int j = 0; j < zoo.getArraySize(); j++) System.out.print(zoo.get(j) + " ");
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Testing constructor, add(object) and size() ");
    zoo.add("Ant");
    zoo.add("Bison");
    zoo.add("Camel");
    zoo.add("Dog");
    zoo.add("Elephant");
    zoo.add("Frog");
    zoo.add("Giraffe");
    zoo.add("Horse");
    printZoo();
    System.out.println();
}
 }
```

And the Exceptions class

**ListFullException.java**

```
public class ListFullException extends RuntimeException{

public ListFullException(String m){
    super(m);
}
}
```

I hope this will be a great study tool for you, if you feel this has helped you, upvote and accept :) :P

Answer (score 1):

**Fixing your Get Method**

```
public int get(int i){
    for(int index = 0; index< arrays.length; index++) {

    }
    return i;
}
```

Okay, so let's look at this shall we? There's a few values that the user can provide..

```
i < 0
0 < i < size of array <-- The only valid one.
i > size of array
```

So first you need to check for that!

```
if(i > 0 && i < arrays.length) {
    // This is a valid index!
}
```

Okay, so you know it's a valid index. Step two is retrieving the value..

```
return arrays[i];
```

And finally, the return type needs to be set. At the moment it is `int`. It needs to be `String` in this example..

```
public String get(int i)
```

It's that simple! When you call `printZoo()`, you'll see the values and not their indices.

**Onto your Objects**

You can have an array of type `Object` without importing any classes. This will change `arrays` of type `String[]` to..

```
Object[] arrays;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However there is another problem, calling the int i parameter won't work as I have Strings as my arrays. Is there another way like to change the parameter into Object ?

Comment: Still doesnt solve the problem, plus you made your edits after some of us answered his questions, bruh!

Comment: I do apologise, dawg. Your code, by the way, is flawed, homie. And while I'm here, you shouldn't be handing out code like this. The general consensus is to give *knowledge*, not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is printing an int because you are calling `zoo.get(j)` and get() returns ints:

```
public int get(int i){
for(int index = 0; index< arrays.length; index++) {

}
return i;
```

You need to return a String, something along the lines of:

```
public String get(int i){
    return arrays[i];
}
```

Comment: Well this was spontaneous xD

Comment: @ProgrammingNewb it literally printed out 10 nulls

Comment: @Eman, that means that your add method isn't actually writing into your array.

Comment: @Choirbean Yeah, I'm pretty sure my add code is wrong.

Comment: it is correct, but missing bits and bobs, i have your working code, with one extra class, check it out in my Long Edit